# Generic Makefile handling unit testing and folder structure

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm going back to C++ and, even though I'm not a beginner in programming and OOP, I'm quite new in the C++ world and I've not mastered the art of Makefiles.

I'd like to know what you think about my third Makefile and the folder structure that I use. Don't hesitate to make any comments you think necessary.

Here is the folder structure of the "project":

```
out/   ---   *.exe and *.zip
tmp/   ---   *.o
lib/
|   catch/   ---   Unit testing framework
|   |   inc/
|   |   |   catch.hpp
inc/   ---   Headers
|   Factorial.hpp
src/   ---   Source files
|   Factorial.cpp
|   main.cpp
tst/   ---   Tests specific source files
|   FactorialTest.cpp
|   MathTest.cpp
|   mainTest.cpp
Makefile
```

It is designed to support unit testing (here using [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch)) with the `tst` folder.

I didn't know how to use external libraries with C++, so I created a `lib` folder to put Catch in. I thought libraries could be downloaded from the `configure.sh` script in the future. Does it sound like a "professional" solution for larger projects?

The Makefile :

```bash
CXX           := g++
LD            := g++

EXEC          := factorial
FLAGS         := -Wall
CXXFLAGS      := $(FLAGS)
LDFLAGS       := $(FLAGS)
INC           := -I inc
SRC           := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ           := $(SRC:src/%.cpp=tmp/%.o)

EXEC_TEST     := test
FLAGS_TEST    := $(FLAGS)
CXXFLAGS_TEST := $(CXXFLAGS)
LDFLAGS_TEST  := $(LDFLAGS)
INC_TEST      := $(INC) -I lib/catch/inc
SRC_TEST      := $(wildcard tst/*.cpp)
OBJ_TEST      := $(filter-out tmp/main.o, $(OBJ)) $(SRC_TEST:tst/%.cpp=tmp/%.o)

.SUFFIXES:

# --------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: all
all: out/$(EXEC)

out/$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    @$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ && echo "[OK]  $@"

# --------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: test
test: out/$(EXEC_TEST)

out/$(EXEC_TEST): $(OBJ_TEST)
    @$(LD) $(LDFLAGS_TEST) $^ -o $@ && echo "[OK]  $@"

# --------------------------------------------------------------

tmp/%.o: src/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< $(INC) -o $@ && echo "[OK]  $@"

tmp/%.o: tst/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS_TEST) -c $< $(INC_TEST) -o $@ && echo "[OK]  $@"

# --------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: clean, clear
clean clear:
    @rm -f out/* && echo "[CL]  out/"
    @rm -f tmp/* && echo "[CL]  tmp/"

.PHONY: archive, zip
archive zip:
    @zip -x out/* tmp/* lib/* -q -r out/$(EXEC)-$(shell date '+%F').zip . && echo "[OK]  out/$(EXEC)-$(shell date '+%F').zip"
```

The Makefile is to be used via `all` and `test` targets, which build the final executable and the unit testing executable respectively.

I tried to avoid duplicating `tmp/%.o: src/%.cpp` and `tmp/%.o: tst/%.cpp` recipes with `test` target-specific variables buy it didn't work because there are variables in targets' and dependencies' names.

PS: It's also my third post on the Stack Exchange Network, so please feel free to make remarks about anything that is not "StackExchange-compliant".

Comment: Do you need Catch in your source tree?  You should be able to install it on your build machine(s) (e.g. `aptitude install catch`) and just use it like any other library.  It's a header-only library, and it installs to `/usr/include`, so you don't even need to change `CXXFLAGS` or `LDLIBS`.

Comment: As I am a student, I can't install the software I want on the university's machines. This PHP Composer / NPM style allows me to easily switch from one machine to another. I've seen the first paragraphs of Boost and another framework; it seems that all of them use the system install approach.

Comment: Fair enough (but consider asking your sysadmins for it - it sounds like something that could be useful to others, too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume throughout this answer that you're targeting GNU Make.  It's available on all targets that matter, and it simplifies your world no end if you can avoid pandering to the idiosyncrasies of the manifold implementations of Make supplied with operating systems.

### Object files depend on headers

This is the biggest thing that I think could be improved; I think it's probably a whole question in itself.  Your object files naturally depend on the corresponding C++ source files, but *they also need rebuilding when their headers change*.  Consider including generated makefiles that tell make how the object files depend on the headers; for a suitable recipe, see the Stack Overflow question "[Makefile, header dependencies](//stackoverflow.com/q/2394609)", and for a longer exposition, read "[Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)" by Paul D. Smith.  I normally use something like

```
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

%.d: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $@ $<
```

### More warnings

It's good to see that you're using `-Wall`.  I also recommend

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses
CXXFLAGS += -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++
```

The first line above always helps; the second does sometimes improve my code (you'll want to make use of `-isystem` to quieten your library includes, if you want to  make the latter bearable).

### Output directory

[Rules of makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) advises that

> #### Life is simplest if the targets are built in the current working directory.
>
> Use `VPATH` to locate the sources from the objects directory, not to locate the objects from the sources directory.

That's certainly something to consider, though it might already be too painful to change.  I certainly prefer out-of-tree builds, so I can clean up with `rm -rf build/` and be left with just my sources.

### Hiding commands

I appreciate that you don't want a wall of text, but when you're debugging (or on an automated build host where you want a complete record of the build), then you might want to override this, and actually see which commands were run.  You can make the behaviour adjustable, like this:

```
QUIET := @
ECHO := @echo
ifneq ($(QUIET),@)
ECHO := @true
endif
```

Use it for your commands:

```
clean clear:
    $(ECHO) "[CL]  out/"
    $(QUIET)$(RM) out/*
    $(ECHO) "[CL]  tmp/"
    $(QUIET)$(RM) tmp/*
```

I changed the order to print first, like Make does, according to the Principle of Least Surprise.  It makes it more obvious what action was in progress when any error occurs.

Now, when you need to see the actual commands, you can `make QUIET=` to override the value and get the full output again.  IIRC, the Linux kernel uses a similar system (toggled by a `KConfig` setting), as does Qt's `qmake` (toggled with `CONFIG += silent` in the `.pro` file).

### Re-use Make's pre-defined commands

Instead of writing

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< $(INC) -o $@

%: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS_TEST) $^ -o $@
```

you can make the rules more like the built-in versions (that you can see with `make --print-database`):

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

%: $(OBJ)
    $(LINK.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

Adapted to use `QUIET` and `ECHO`, that's

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(ECHO) "[OK]  $@"
    $(QUIET)$(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

%: $(OBJ)
    $(ECHO) "[OK]  $@"
    $(QUIET)$(LINK.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

You'll need to ensure that your include path is in `CXXFLAGS`, and you might need target-dependent flags:

```
CXXFLAGS += $(INC)

tmp/%: CXXFLAGS=$(CXXFLAGS_TEST)
```

### All makefiles should have...

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

Without this, a failed command could leave a part-written output that a subsequent make believes is up-to-date.

### Finally

Here's a tyni tyop:

```
.PHONY: clean, clear
```

Lose that `,` - you've said that `clean,` is a phony target, not `clean` as you intended.